# Pronunciation of Mathematicians' name

Tags: reference-request

Is there any online resource for the audio pronunciations of the names of mathematicians ? Thanks.

Comment: A name is pronounced usually the same way irrespective of the person's profession. Search for "pronouncing Barrack Obama" or whatever the name is, in some web search engine.

Comment: @PVanchinathan It more likely to find this for Barack Obama than, for instance, [Thomas Joannes Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Joannes_Stieltjes). The good news is: often Wikipedia gives the [IPA notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). It's not easy for the casual reader, but it's better that nothing.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut You are right: Wikipedia is a  general purpose web site for information;  wikipedia is known to  and used by non-mathematicians even non-academics. My point is no need to think of this as a question for mathematic forum, one should exhaust those sources first. (For example questions about how to solve a  specific mathematical  problem using software  MATLAB are discouraged here, rightly so).

Comment: @PVanchinathan I understand. However, I think this question is interesting, even here on MSE: as I commented below on Edu's answer, the answer is more difficult than it seems, and it's likely more difficult to find an answer for scientist than for more "mediatic" people. It's a bit like a "notation" question, and as for notation, anwers differ according to language and/or country. By the way, there is a Matlab tag (to be used with care...), as well as  Mathematica, Maple and other mathematical software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know [this one](http://pronouncemath.blogspot.ie/), **Pronunciation of Mathematicians' Names**

Comment: Interesting site. As was to be expected, there is a problem with this though: the pronunciation often depends on the language. Thus the site is probably no too bad for the english pronunciation, but for instance, some french names are not very well pronunced (for a french ear), and some german names are usually not pronunced in french like in german. Two well known examples are Gauss and Euler. Same remark for most ancient greek names. So one must be aware that this wite will not give the definitive answer for all possible situations.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks.